# Compiler version changes when eclipse crashes

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

I am using eclipse galileo for my project. There are around 50 projects. Initially I set the compiler version as `1.5` in Workspace settings. So all the projects compiles in `1.5`. When eclipse crashes, I need to restart the eclipse again. But now the compiler version in each project is changed to `1.4`. If I check the compiler version in workspace settings, its `1.5`, but if I check in each project its set to `1.4`. I need to manually change the compiler version in each project to `1.5`.

Is there any other alternate solution to avoid manually setting the compiler version in each project?

Comment: After setting the compiler version to 1.5, do you close the eclipse once(so that changes are persisted)? It happened to me once if I do the change and do not close and restart eclipse but kill the eclipse process, the changes were not saved.

Comment: Yes, I closed the eclipse. If I restart the eclipse again, it is working fine. The issue occurs only when eclipse or system crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It is an unfortunate resort but have you tried backing up the project.properties file for a given project?  There is also a default.properties file which is controlling default settings for all projects.  Of course, you will need new backups when you change settings on purpose.

Before you do that though, please confirm that you have closed eclipse normally after you set all the compiler options correctly, before you re-try the event leading to the crash.  There are things that eclipse does not save properly until you exit the IDE and these settings will obviously get wiped out if the IDE terminates abnormally.

Comment: Nope. I have not tried backing up project.properties and default.properties files. If I restart the eclipse again, it is working fine. The issue occurs only when eclipse or system crashes